# How do I convert a Numpy array of dimensions (3, 2998, 2403) into (2998, 2403, 3)?

Tags: python, image-processing

[image]

This is the current shape (channels, height, width), how do I convert it into the usual image format of - (height, width, channels)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.transpose`:

```
final = np.transpose(final, (1, 2, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:
Either you do

```
final = final.reshape(2998, 2403, 3)
```

or you do:

```
final = final.permute(1, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.moveaxis(array, source, destination)` to move axis. Here source axis is `0` and destination axis is `-1` (last)

```py
final = np.moveaxis(final,0,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be np.moveaxis such as:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.array([[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]],[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]],[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]])
    print(a.shape)
    print(a)
    b = np.moveaxis(a,0, -1)
    print(b.shape)
    print(b)
```

with output:
before np.moveaxis
(3, 2, 4)
[[[1 2 3 4]
[4 5 6 7]]

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [4 5 6 7]]

[[1 2 3 4]
 [4 5 6 7]]]
```

after np.moveaxis:

```
(2, 4, 3)
[[[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]
  [3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]

 [[4 4 4]
  [5 5 5]
  [6 6 6]
  [7 7 7]]]
```